# Which software to use for Gaussian regression on spatially and temporally correlated data?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

Which tools out there could help me to do a Gaussian process regression on spatially and temporally correlated data?

My main aim is to extract values for a particular covariance model. I know that in Machine learning area a similar technique is referred to as Gaussian processes (GP). In the context of GP, covariances are called kernels.

I have acquired data from multiple temperature sensors deployed in a city. My data is non-uniform distributed, meaning that samples (measurements) from a different sensor are not acquired at the same time. Furthermore, the number of samples per sensor is uneven.

Comment: I'm not aware of software which generically solves this problem; depending on what kinds of tools you're comfortable using and exactly what you want to obtain as a result, you'll have to do a small or large amount of programming. Perhaps you could be more specific about what you know and what you want to know?

Comment: I read the book by Cressie, Statistics for Spatio-temporal data. I followed the work of Tilmann Gneiting (Nonseparable covariance functions for Space-time data) I recreated Gneiting experiment and learned how to extract scaling parameters for a particular covariance model. However, his approach is valid when spatial data is acquired at the same time at every sensor(data source). I am looking for a way to calculate covariances in a more dynamical system.

Comment: I am proficient in Python, but I am willing to learn another language if it would make my life easier. I was looking into Scikit-learn library http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_co2.html, but that case focuses only on temporal correlation, and I don't know how could take into account the spatial component.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the Gaussian Process chapter of *Bayesian Data Analysis* (3rd edition) works through an example using multiple temporal kernels to do inference on a temporal trend. Perhaps you could do something similar: multiple kernel learning where one kernel is a spatial trend (instead of a temporal trend).